# python + cx_freeze 'cannot get zipimporter instance'

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I saw [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447833/cx-freeze-cannot-get-zipimporter) relating to this, however it did not really answer my question.

I have written a program intended to be able to be used without needing an installation of python; I used cx_freeze to achieve this. I wrote a setup.py, and ran it in cmd. This all works fine, although I do get some 'missing module' warnings, it assures me that this may not be a problem:

```
    Missing modules:
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading
? ce imported from os
? doctest imported from heapq
? getopt imported from base64, quopri
? grp imported from shutil, tarfile
? org.python.core imported from copy
? os.path imported from os, py_compile, shutil
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from posixpath, shutil, tarfile
? subprocess imported from os
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.
```

(I am running Windows 8, never got round to updating to 8.1)

After exporting, I am presented with two files; 'python34.dll' and 
'T-Backup.exe'. When I run T-backup.exe I get the above error.

Here's my setup.py in case it's neeeded:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if (sys.platform == "win32"):
    base = "Win32GUI"

exe = Executable(
        script = "<path>\\T-Backup.py",
        icon = "<path>\\Icon.ico",
        targetName = "<path>\\exe\\T-Backup.exe",
        base = base
        )
includefiles = ["<path>\\Icon.ico","<path>\\backupfrom.tbk","<path>\\backupto.tbk"]

setup(
    name = "T-Backup",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Backs up Terraria Worlds and Players.",
    author = "Sam Poirier (darthmorf)",
    options = {'build_exe': {'include_files':includefiles}},
    executables = [exe]



)
```

Thanks for your help.

-darthmorf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot comment, so I am answering:

I think you are on a 64bit system and you will never get a base other than 'None'. Try changing

```
base = None
if (sys.platform == "win32"):
    base = "Win32GUI"
```

To

```
base = "Win32GUI"
```

This fixed a lot of my issues, that were similar to what you described...

If you could show what modules you actually imported then I could probably be of more use.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this when I get back to my PC, along with posting my modules. (I am running 64 bit)

Comment: I am using 'shutil', 'time', 'os', and 'datetime' (as dt).